# python retrieve all data from mysql table after if statement

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to stackoverflow and asking this question,since it seems to be nowhere.

I have two tables.With one table i need to check another table datas, and if the datas are same then it should retrieve the value from the same data.

Problem: I can only match and view the last row of data not the entire rows in table.After `if` statement,if i print the `i` it gets only the last row not entire row.

Question: How can i access and print all the rows after if statement?

My coding:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 FROM adarsh1")

cursor1 = db.cursor()
    # execute SQL select statement
cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM filename1")
    # commit your changes
db.commit()

    #here fetchall() gets all the rows and we append carnames to key words
for i1 in cursor1.fetchall():
    print 'hello'
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    print 'hello'

if i in i1:
    print i
else:
    print i1
```

Comment: why you have wrong indentation in bottom of your code ? is it same this in your real code ?

Comment: after your `for il in cursor1....` loop completes, then i1 will be the very last row - you need your `for i in il:` loop indented so it is part of the `for il in cursor1..` loop.

Comment: I meant - your `if` statement should be indented to be part of your for `il in cursor`...` loop - and it could be that the `for i in cursor.` is wrong indented too. also - no need for the commit - your code snippet does not make any changes - `SELECT` statements don't need to be comitted.

Comment: could u just provided an edited answer..because i need to check after the if statement for same data..please help!

Comment: One final comment - you will probably find that you can do this row to row comparison far more effectively in SQL, as that is what SQL is designed for.

Comment: so,how should i change the indentation..where should i space them?

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you are trying to do...

Comment: i just need to print the same rows found in both the tables..

Comment: @sarkite I think it would be better for you to ask a new question, 'how to get rows that exists in two tables' or something else that explains more clearly what you are trying to do with the data. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: how to assign i1 to all the rows without the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to read about [indentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) , before start coding python ! As i cant post this simple answer in comment do this :

change this part :

```
for i1 in cursor1.fetchall():
    print 'hello'
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    print 'hello'

if i in i1:
    print i
else:
    print i1
```

to this :

```
for i1 in cursor1.fetchall():
    print 'hello'
    for i in cursor.fetchall():
        print 'hello'

        if i in i1:
             print i
        else:
             print i1
```

and try again ,

Comment: without using for loop ,how can I assign the i1 for all the rows directly?